# html grid has a line on the side

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I only want to see the inner lines of grid, but depending on screen width, there is a line on the right that appears. I'm not sure if this is how grids work or is there a way to fix it?

```css
.grid-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  background-color: #000000;
  padding: 0px;
}

.grid-item {
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 4%;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="main_div">
    <p>Player = </p>
    <p id="player_display" style="font-size: 3rem;"></p>
    <p id="winner_display"></p>

    <div class=grid-container>
      <div class="grid-item" id="1"></div>
      <div class="grid-item" id="2"></div>
      <div class="grid-item" id="3"></div>
      <div class="grid-item" id="4"></div>
      <div class="grid-item" id="5"></div>
      <div class="grid-item" id="6"></div>
      <div class="grid-item" id="7"></div>
      <div class="grid-item" id="8"></div>
      <div class="grid-item" id="9"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="./scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: HTML screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reset for the HTML page.
in your CSS add

```
*{ margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}
```

Comment: This doesn't help

Comment: it works... I try . add this to the css